# copying a file to a new directory, does this just create a new hardlink?

Tags: hard-link

I am attempting to grasp hardlinks. When one copys a file from

```
/dir1/file1
```

to

```
/dir2/file1
```

does this create a hardlink, or is the data actually duplicated and now two hardlinks exist?

Comment: Do you want me to explain `softlink`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It Creates a new file when you copy. Hardlink is something different

`ln fileA fileB` is a hardlink.

`ls -il fileA fileB`

The `i` argument will show the inode on the HD

Here you can see that both fileA and fileB have the same inode number ( 1482256 ), also both files have the same file permissions and the same size, because that ´size´ is on the same inode it does not consume any extra space on your HD !

Now if we would remove the original `fileA`

`rm fileA`

and have a look at the content of the link `fileB`

`cat fileB`

you will still be able to read the funny line of text you typed. (MAGIC !)